# neo4j Regular Expression error

Tags: neo4j

i want to use regular expression to query string start with "+"
my neo4j version is 2.3.8

here is my query:

```
MATCH (n:phone_number) where n.name =~ "\+.*" RETURN n LIMIT 1
```

but it failed:

```
Invalid input '+': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't',          '_', '%', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column 42 (offset: 41))
"MATCH (n:phone_number) where n.name =~ "\+.*" RETURN n LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in neo4j. This workaround should work:

```
MATCH (n:phone_number)
WHERE n.name =~ "\\u002b.*"
RETURN n LIMIT 1;
```

It uses the Java [unicode escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) sequence `\u002b` to represent the "+" character.